# prove that $\;\;\big\{ X \times Y : X\in A\;\land\;Y\in B\big\}$ is a set

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory

How can I prove that

$\;\;\big\{ X \times Y : X\in A\;\land\;Y\in B\big\}$

Is a set when $A$ and $B$ are existing sets ?

I know that $A \times B$ is a set and that I have to use axioms of set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $X\in A$ and $Y\in B$, $X\times Y$ is a set itself. Fix $Y\in B$ and consider the predicate $$P(X\times Y)= X \text{ is an element of } A$$

by the Axiom schema of specification

$$\{X\times Y : P(X\times Y)\}$$ is a set. And now $$\{ X \times Y : X\in A\;\land\;Y\in B\big\}=\bigcup_{Y\in B}\{X\times Y : P(X\times Y)\}$$
and is thus a set.